# Change background image of button programmatically in Visual c++

Tags: c++, .net, visual-c++, c++-cli, clr

There's so few tutorials when it comes to visual c++ and I can't find answers to my problem which is easy for other .net supported languages like C# and VB.

I have a simple UI created with visual c++ compiled with clr. I have button that has a background image set in properties, but I don't know how to change the background image when the button was clicked or mouse hovered.

My images was located in '/asset' directory.

And since I can't find answers for c++, I cannot show any code snippet here.

Hope someone helps. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After an hour of research I finally solved my problems:

```
internal:
        ImageList ^ ImageList1;

private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        ImageList1 = gcnew ImageList;
        ImageList1->ImageSize = System::Drawing::Size(200, 200);
        ImageList1->Images->Add(Image::FromFile("..\\assets\\button_round_red\\button_round_red_selected.png"));
        button2->BackgroundImage = ImageList1->Images[0];
        button2->BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout::Center;
        button2->Size = button2->BackgroundImage->Size;
    }
```